# AWS Security - What happens if I lose my MFA device?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

Having enabled multi-factor authentication for my AWS root account, I feel like there is a risk: My authenticator is on my cell phone. If I lose my cell phone, will I be locked out of my root account forever? I mean, obviously I can download another authenticator, it's the QR code I scanned that concerns me: I'm uncertain that I will have the necessary access to retrieve/regenerate it. Advice, anyone?

Answer (score 6):

It’s actually very easy to generate codes identical to those generated by AWS IAM Virtual MFA Devices, on your computer!  You just have to keep a **secure backup** of the secret key which is visible to you during the “Manage MFA Device” process.

During device registration, underneath the QR code, expand the “Show secret key for manual configuration”: copy that string and keep it encrypted somewhere safe.  Then proceed to register your phone &c. as normal.

In future, should you lose your phone, you can generate the current Time–based One–time Password code by running the secret key you saved through the following python snippet:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from base64 import b32decode

from oath import totp

SEED = 'SECRET_KEY'  # replace content of this string
                     # with your saved secret key

print totp(
    b32decode(SEED).encode('hex'),
    format='dec6',
    period=30)
```

(You’ll need to `pip install oath` first, it’s not part of python’s standard library.)

Comment: The produced code is rejected and also not matching the one from Google Authenticator app. I'm positive that I correctly copied and pasted the secret key.

Comment: @Raffael the culprit in your case might be that your system clock is not sufficiently synchronised

Answer (score 3):

If you lose access to the MFA codes on the root account, [you can contact Amazon and they will disable MFA so you can log in](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/aws-mfa-support).

From experience, they respond within hours.

Answer (score 2):

My Personal experience when I lost my MFA device for AWS account.

1. First you have to contact AWS support through [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/).
2. Then Support person will contact you and ask for your email.
3. He will send secret code to your email and ask to repeat it.
4. If those records are same then you can request to dissable MFA from
   your account.
5. Finally you can log to AWS console with previour credentials or with
   new one.
6. At the end of the process They will send a reply message which asking for
   your comment about their support process.

Response will come within hours.Specially I needs to mention that there customer support is absolutely brilliant.

Comment: So basically your AWS ccount is only as secure as your email password...

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a ticket to AWS. After that they ask approximately 5-6 questions like your phone number, last numbers of your credit card etc. Finally they reset it.